# In "between-class" scatter matrix, what does "overall mean" $m$ refer to?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, means

In "between-class" scatter matrix, what does "overall mean" $m$ refer to?

Because the formulation is

$$\sum_{i=1}^c N_i (m_i - m) (m_i - m)^T$$

where $N_i$s is the size of $i$th sample (each column is a sample), $m_i$ is the sample mean of $i$th sample. But what does $m$, the overall mean, refer to?

Comment: Did you mean the $N_i$ are the sample sizes, rather than the sample means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N$ be the total number of observations, and $N_i$ the number of observation in $i$th class. Total of $c$ classes, hence the overall mean is
$$
m = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^c \sum_{j=1}^{N_i} m_{ij} ,
$$
where $m_{ij}$ is the $j$th observation from $i$th class.

Comment: Why does one take $N_i m_i$? Rather than just $m_i$.

Comment: Why wouldn't the overall mean be the "mean of sample means"?

Comment: It is. The weighted mean of the means. If $N_i = N_j$ for all $i$ and $j$, then it is just the "regular" mean

Comment: I don't get why one takes $N_i$ times the sample mean, because that's not the sample mean then anymore? But sample mean times $N_i$. Then I read that you  take the mean of sample means times $N_i$ over classes.

Comment: Oh except that I probably forgot that each observation is a vector of > 1 length and therefore they have separate means.

Comment: Just ignore  the last expression. The overall mean is just the mean of the all $N = \sum_{i=1}^c N_i$ observations.

Answer (score 1):

Just join all $c$ of the samples into one sample. The overall mean is the mean of that.

Comment: What do you mean by "join"?

Comment: @mavavilj : Suppose $m_{1,1}, \ldots , m_{1,p}$ is the first sample, $m_{2,1}, \ldots, m_{2,q}$ is the second, $m_{3,1}, \ldots, m_{3,r}$ is the third, and so on. Then $$m_{11}, \ldots, m_{1,p},\quad m_{2,1}, \ldots, m_{2,q}, \quad m_{3,1}, \ldots, m_{3,r}, \quad \ldots\ldots$$ is the sample that you get when you join all of them. $\qquad$